# 'cout' statement not being executed

Tags: c++, cout, fibonacci

The following program  is to find the sum of even-valued fibonacci terms not more than four million.
The last 'cout' statement in this program doesn't get executed at all. Why is it? Help please.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int a, b, c, sum, sum1, sum2;
    a = 1;
    b = 2;
    sum2 = 0;

    cout << b << endl;
    c = a + b;

    sum1 = c;

    while (c <= 4000000)
    {
        a = b;
        b = c;
        if ((a + b) <= 4000000)
        {
            c = a + b;
            if (c%2 == 0)
            {
                sum2 = sum2 + c;
                cout << c << endl;
            }
        }
    }

    cout << "The sum of even fibonacci numbers not greater than 4 million is: " << (sum1 + sum2); //Not being executed
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Did you try to flush ?

Comment: You definitely have an infinite loop in there.

Comment: @stefan: True. But since this is not even the real problem, I will remove the comment.

Answer (score 5):

I can't execute the program, but I think that your program never ends, which is why you never get to that statement. Your outer `while` loop will keep on going unitl `c <= 4000000`. However, you only increment `c` if and only if `(a + b) <= 4000000`, so `c` never goes beyond 4 million.

To fix this, you could try the below:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int a, b, c, sum, sum1, sum2;
    a = 1;
    b = 2;
    sum2 = 0;   

    cout << b << endl;
    c = a + b; 

    sum1 = c;

    while (c <= 4000000)
    {
        a = b;
        b = c;
        c = a + b; //Update c regardless.
        if (c <= 4000000)
        {           
            if (c%2 == 0)
            {
                sum2 = sum2 + c;
                cout << c << endl;
            }
        }
    }


    cout << "The sum of even fibonacci numbers not greater than 4 million is: " << (sum1 + sum2); //Not being executed
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It would be simpler just to remove `if ((a + b) <= ...`, the program still achieves the correct result.

Comment: @remyabel: Yes I agree. I tried to give an answer which does less modifications to the one the OP provided.

Comment: btw, isn't sum1 useless ?

Comment: @Thomas: Yes I think so. If I am understanding this correctly, the code should give an answer which is off by `sum1`.

Comment: npinti's solution is the best IMO. If the program was to print all fibonacci numbers not more than 4 million, in place of just even fibonacii numbers, his solution would work, but just removing the "if ((a+b) <= . . ." would print one output over 4 million.

Answer (score 1):

```
while ( c <= 4000000 )
{
    // ...
    if ( ( a + b ) <= 4000000 )
    {
        c = a + b;    // i.e. <= 4000000
        // ...
    }
}
```

How do you expect that loop to terminate?